# Total executed lines gcov

Tags: ios5, code-coverage, gcov

I'm starting with code coverage to measure how good are my tests. I already have all my program compiled to use gcov and I also have my .gcda and .gcno files.

If I execute something like: "gcov --branch-probabilities --no-output mySourceFile.m" I get as a result the amount of lines executed, branches executed... But from just one file, I need that same measure but from my whole project. Is there anyway of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool I was looking for it's called gcovr. It's a python script and it summarizes the code coverage total. You just install it, and run it, that's all and it gives you total amount of lines, total executed lines and percentage of executed lines.

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: And [here is a link](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/wiki/gcovr) to the gcovr project documentation and downloads.